# Issues understanding 'interface' in CMAKE target_include_libraries

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm currently doing the CMAKE tutorial.

[CMAKE Tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/index.html)

In step 3, you are adding the following line to a "library", MathFunctions which has a single source file `mysqrt.cpp`.

```
target_include_directories(MathFunctions
          INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
          )
```

The tutorial offers this explanation of `INTERFACE`:

> Remember INTERFACE means things that consumers require but the producer doesn’t.

I'm having trouble understanding this. I'm assuming the following:

1) Consumer is the source project including the `MathFunctions` library

2) Producer is the `MathFunctions` library

But why doesn't the producer need to include the current source directory?

And why can't we use the `PUBLIC` or `PRIVATE` key instead?

Comment: It's like stated in the tutorial: In the given example MathFunctions doesn't need the headers (the source doesn't include any of the headers) while targets that link against MathFunctions need it (which will not work with the PRIVATE key). PUBLIC should work too but in some projects might cause conflicts when there are multiple headers with the same name and this is an educational example.